# A Recursive Function for Backtracking in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to implement permutation with backtracking algorithm. My 'list' variable can't catch the result from the _permute function and the L1 value changes every time. What went wrong with my code?

```js
var permute = function(nums) {
  if (nums.lenght === 0) return [];
  var list = [],
    temp = [];
  _permute(list, temp, nums);
  return list;
};

function _permute(L1, Ltemp, nums) {
  if (Ltemp.length === nums.length) {
    console.log('Ltemp', Ltemp, 'L1', L1);
    L1.push(Ltemp);
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (Ltemp.includes(nums[i])) continue;
    Ltemp.push(nums[i]);
    _permute(L1, Ltemp, nums);
    Ltemp.pop();
  }
}
permute([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Try to write a pseudo-code, then translate it into JavaScript. It seems your code's logic is not complete

Comment: The idea is to push all completed result (Ltemp) to L1 and return the result. ex. Input: [1,2,3], the output should be in the format of -- Output:
[
  [1,2,3],
  [1,3,2],
  [2,1,3],
  [2,3,1],
  [3,1,2],
  [3,2,1]
]